# Does the freequent use of CAT command badly affect the hard disk performance?

Tags: disk, ext4

One the programs I've written requires merging **many files** into **one**, **every 3 seconds.**

The merged file can be bigger than 1GB.

I'm using `cat` command to do this.

`Cat` seems to work pretty fast even when merging large files, but I don't know how it works internally.
 I'm worried whether iteration of `cat` command will badly slow down the hard disk, at program runtime.

Comment: There almost certainly a better approach to your data merging method, in your 'software'. *I think you should focus on that, rather than the best 'work around'.*

Comment: My program is a video streamer. It can download online videos as chunks. While downloading, I want the user to be able to play it. So, Each chunk downloaded should be instantly merge with the main video file, because at the time user is watching it. This is the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by affecting hard disk performance or by the internal works of cat, but the thing here is that you are doing very I/O expensive stuff: reading from the disk (the "many files") and writing to the disk (the "one" file).

Combined with that you do this quite often, you are doing a lot of work on your harddisk. If you are doing this on one harddisk, continuously, it will affect performance. Not per se because of `cat`, I believe `cat` isn't especially an issue here, but because of the intrinsic I/O effect of your functionality.

If you keep on reading and writing from a disk (especially when it is the same), you'd have a noticable performance effect on all other programs that want to read or write. How much is just a question of the speed of the system, if there are any breaks in reading/writing at all, how many disks you are using, etc etc.

So yes there CAN be, but as with all performance questions: you should really TEST if it is the case. That is the only valid metric.

Comment: My program is a video streamer. It can download online videos as chunks. While downloading, I want it to be able to play it too. Each chunk downloaded should be instantly merge with the main video file, because at the time user is watching it. So, this is the situation. I would be glad if you can provide a bit specific answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but the point is still valid: `cat` has nothing much to do with it, it is more the concept that needs checking. As it is dependent on the users hardware you should do field testing with your type of files (kb/s would matter, harddiskwrite and read speed, etc). If the system is swapping you'd get a LOT of performance loss if you keep writing as well.